# HTTP PostAsync returns nothing

Tags: c#, http, asynchronous

The code below works for sending a HTTP post to Webhook.site, but when doing the same request to my own azurewebsite the debugger stops at postasync and the ’response’ variable remains null.

My azure website returns 200 from json-string POST from ReqBin. My excel application can send working http posts to Webhook.site using the code below, just not to my own azurewebsite. What am I missing?

Some resources suggest SSL validation might cause problems? Not sure if this is the case.

```
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostRequest(IRibbonControl control)
{
    var content = new StringContent(json_object.ToString(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    //This is where i input my own website and it doesn't work
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("https://webhook.site/9b994ad0-81a1-496f-b910-d48d0567b1b8", content).ConfigureAwait(false); 

    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return response;
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You might want to invest in application logging so you can view exceptions and other debugging information in your deployed code.

Comment: What do you mean "returns nothing"? Empty content? Which http status code it returns?

Comment: @Leff the deugger simply stops on the postasync row and the 'response' variable remains unchanged (null).

Comment: "Returns null" is entirely different to "returns nothing". Edit that information into your question, please.

Comment: Yes @Ian Kemp, I edited my question.

Comment: If you are getting a status of 200 OK then the connection was good but the query is not returning any data.  You would not get a 200 OK if the TLS authentication is failing.  I'm assuming the server code is properly returning the 200 OK.   If there is java code running on the server the java may not be completing and that may be the reason for no data.

Answer (score 0):

To see result of postAsync method in debug execute 2 steps. Screenshot: [postAsync debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Exg78.png)

1. **return HttpResponseMessage** from method with postAsync:

   ```
   private static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> methodWithPostAsync(){
   ...
   response = await client.PostAsync(url, data);
   return response
   }
   ```
2. call method and **wait for response message status**:

   ```
   Task<HttpResponseMessage> content= methodWithPostAsync();
   while (!content.IsCompleted)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("busy");
       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
   }
   ```